# ASP.NET Friendly URLs and default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms, friendly-url

I've implemented Friendly URLs in a Webform project but it allows a user to go to either the root of the website or /default. I really want to get rid of the /default option by having it always just route to the root. I've tried using

`routes.MapPageRoute("", "Default", "~/")`

but that doesn't seem to effect anything.

Anyone now the proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this will be through IIS not in code. It will create a 301 redirect from requests to default.aspx to the root.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="default page" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^default\.aspx$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```